# Merge sort implementation for counting Inversion of an array

Tags: java, mergesort

Below is my implementation for Inversion of an array. For some inputs it produces the required result. For eg :

1 : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 -> 0 inversion (Correct)

2 : 1000,999,998,997,.......3,2,1 -> 499500 inversion (Correct)

3 : 1,3,5,2,4,6 -> 3 inversion (Correct)

But for

4 : 9,10,8,1,4,7,6,2,5,3 -> 41 inversion (Incorrect). The correct answer is 33.

```
public class Assignment1 {
static int[] result = new int[10];

public static long divideW (int Arr[]) {
    long countLeft ;
    long countRight ;
    long countMerge ;

    int mid = (Arr.length)/2;

    if (Arr.length <= 1)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int leftArr[] = new int [mid];
        int rightArr[] = new int [Arr.length - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
            leftArr[i] = Arr[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < rightArr.length ; j++){
            rightArr[j] = Arr[mid + j];
        }   
        countLeft = divideW (leftArr);
        countRight = divideW (rightArr);

        //int[] result = new int[Arr.length];
        countMerge = conquer(leftArr, rightArr, result);
        return (countLeft + countRight + countMerge);
    }
}
public static long conquer (int []l, int[]r, int[] result) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    long count = 0;
    while ((i < l.length) && (j < r.length)) {
    if (l[i] <= r [j]) {
        result[k] = l[i++];
    }
    else if (l[i] > r[j]) {
        result[k] = r[j++];
        count += l.length - i;
    }
    ++k;
    }
    while ( i < l.length) {
        result[k++] = l[i++];
    }
    while ( j < r.length) {
        result[k++] = r[j++];
    }
    return count;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Assignment1 rs = new Assignment1();
    int anArr[] = {9,10,8,1,4,7,6,2,5,3};

    System.out.println (rs.divideW(anArr));

    for (int i = 0 ; i < result.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println (result[i]);
    }  
    }
}
```

Comment: @PLB The goal isn't to simply removed the Homework tag. You need to make substantial edits. If the question is too specific or just horrible flag it, so it can be closed or deleted (like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174910/basic-java-teaching-recources)). If the question is great, _only_ then should you simply remove the Homework tag, but this is rare.

Comment: upsi, sorry :) ok I'll watch out from now on

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not correct because it does not pass the sorted array into the **conquer**
function

Below is the code I have implemented using C#.

```
using System;

namespace SortingAlgos
{
    public class InversionCountUsingMergeSort
    {
        public static long InversionCount { get; set; }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load an array
            int[] arrayInts = { 9, 10, 8, 1, 4, 7, 6, 2, 5, 3 };// { 10, 4, 7, 8, 6, 2, 3, 5 };//{1,3,5,2,4,6}--->3;//{ 9, 10, 8, 1, 4, 7, 6, 2, 5, 3 }-->41;//{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }--->0;//{ 10, 4, 7, 8, 6, 2, 3, 5 }; //LoadInts();

            Console.WriteLine("========= UnSorted Array Items ==========");

            //Print an unsorted array
            PrintInts(arrayInts);

            Console.WriteLine("========== Inversion Count =========");
            //Sort the array
            arrayInts = MergeSort(arrayInts);

            //Print Sorted array
            PrintInts(arrayInts);
            Console.WriteLine(InversionCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int[] MergeSort(int[] arrayInts)
        {
            if (arrayInts.Length <= 1)
            {
                return arrayInts;
            }
            else
            {
                int[] result = new int[arrayInts.Length];

                int midPoint = arrayInts.Length / 2;
                int[] leftArray = new int[midPoint];
                int[] rightArray;
                if (arrayInts.Length % 2 == 0)
                {
                    rightArray = new int[midPoint];
                }
                else
                {
                    rightArray = new int[midPoint + 1];
                }

                for (int indexLeft = 0; indexLeft < midPoint; indexLeft++)
                {
                    leftArray[indexLeft] = arrayInts[indexLeft];
                }
                int indexRight = 0;
                for (int indexOnArryInts = midPoint; indexOnArryInts < arrayInts.Length; indexOnArryInts++)
                {
                    if (indexRight < rightArray.Length)
                    {
                        rightArray[indexRight] = arrayInts[indexOnArryInts];
                        indexRight++;
                    }
                }

                leftArray = MergeSort(leftArray);
                rightArray = MergeSort(rightArray);
                return MergeArrays(leftArray, rightArray);

            }
        }

        private static int[] MergeArrays(int[] leftArray, int[] rightArray)
        {
            int arraySize = leftArray.Length + rightArray.Length;
            int[] arrayFinal = new int[arraySize];
            int leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
            {
                if (leftIndex < leftArray.Length && rightIndex < rightArray.Length)
                {
                    if (leftArray[leftIndex] <= rightArray[rightIndex])
                    {
                        arrayFinal[index] = leftArray[leftIndex];
                        leftIndex++;                    
                    }
                    else if (leftArray[leftIndex] > rightArray[rightIndex])
                    {
                        arrayFinal[index] = rightArray[rightIndex];
                        rightIndex++;
                        InversionCount += leftArray.Length - leftIndex;
                    }
                }
                else if (leftIndex < leftArray.Length)
                {
                    arrayFinal[index] = leftArray[leftIndex];
                    leftIndex++;
                }
                else if (rightIndex < rightArray.Length)
                {
                    arrayFinal[index] = rightArray[rightIndex];
                    rightIndex++;
                }
            }
            return arrayFinal;
        }

        private static void PrintInts(int[] arrayInts)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < arrayInts.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", arrayInts[index]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your answer (I assume it is correct) the following:

```
countMerge = conquer(leftArr, rightArr, result);
```

You just do conquer part on **unsorted** arrays (leftArr, rightArr) that's why the number of inversions different. I changed this code as below and it works:

```
Arrays.sort(leftArr);
Arrays.sort(rightArr);
countMerge = conquer(leftArr, rightArr, result);
```

Comment: Arrays.sort will sort it but it would not be a merge sort implementation. Acc to the merge sort implementation i should divide the problems which happens through the divideW(leftArr) and divideW(rightArr) calls and conquer the problem through call to the conquer function.

Comment: Your goal to count number of iversions or to merge sort the array or both of them? If the first one, my solution is working, is the second one all is working, if the third one just pass merge-sorted arrays to conquer methods. I point you to the mistake in counting instead of providing full-working implementation. 
Just a hint, rewrite `divideW` to have sorted passed array after it

Comment: i figured it out what was the problem and got the right answers now. But am still not able to grasp how it was solved. At the end of divideW method before the return statement i had to put a for loop like for (int k=0; k<Arr.length; k++){ Arr[k]=result[k]; }. This populates the original arr which i had. It makes a difference but why why why..